# How to Draw Projectile Trajectory with Unity3d's built-in Physics Engine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game that will fling a projectile that reacts to physics forces.  I am using the built in Unity Physics in the game, but I am drawing the trajectory of the projectile before it is launched.  To do so, I'm using a LineRenderer and a simple Physics class I rolled to compute the positions:

```
public class SlingPhysics
{
    private Vector3 HalfGravity;
    private float ForceMultiplier;

    public void Init(Vector3 gravity, float slingForce, float mass, float drag)
    {
        HalfGravity = gravity / 2.0f;
        ForceMultiplier = slingForce / mass / (1 + drag);
    }

    public Vector3 GetPosition(Vector3 start, Vector3 direction, float timeDelta)
    {
        Vector3 pos = direction * (timeDelta * ForceMultiplier);
        pos.y += (HalfGravity.y * timeDelta * timeDelta);
        return start + pos;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Computes an array of Trajectory object positions by time.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Number of positions filled into the buffer</returns>
    /// <param name="startPos">Starting Position</param>
    /// <param name="direction">Direction (and magnitude) vector</param>
    /// <param name="timeIncrement">Time increment of the samples</param>
    /// <param name="yFloor">Minimum height, below which is clipped</param>
    /// <param name="positions">Buffer to fill with positions</param>
    public int GetPositions(Vector3 startPos, Vector3 direction, float timeIncrement, float yFloor, Vector3[] positions)
    {
        int maxItems = positions.Length;
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < maxItems; i++)
        {
            Vector3 pos = GetPosition(startPos, direction, timeIncrement * i);
            if (pos.y < yFloor)
                break;
            positions[i] = pos;
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

This works great and (somewhat surprisingly) exactly matches the actual trajectory that the projectile ends up traveling when launched and is governed by the Unity Physics engine.

But now, we decided to introduce drag on to the Rigidbody and the trajectory is no longer perfect.  I could continue to try to change my physics model to match what Unity is doing, but this seems like a losing battle.

Is there any way to precompute and draw the trajectory using the Unity Physics engine?

If not, how are drag and angular drag implemented mathematically in Unity Physics?

Is there a documentation source for Unity's (5.3.4) Physics implementation?

Comment: I've searched for the same thing, but couldn't find any official documentation. However, it is fairly easy to just test it out yourself. I don't remember off the top of my head, but I used a rigidbody with drag value and one without and wrote just a simple script to simulate the drag and tried a couple of the typical formulas and it turned out to be one of the simple ones. Then you'd still have to manually calculate everything to match Unity's implementation, because they don't offer any API for what you want.

Comment: Xarbrough, thanks.  I'll track down the drag formula and give it a try, despite Programmer's sage advice to avoid the folly of chasing Unity.  My code is really simple, so a little more complexity won't kill me; hopefully it ends there.  And when the next great Physics engine comes out, I'll cross that bridge then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to calculate drag in to match the Unity engine is to compute and keep track of velocity in FixedUpdate and then update velocity for Drag.

The Unity formula for Drag was provided here:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/drag-factor-what-is-it.85504/

It is indeed simple; the key part is this:

```
velocity *= Mathf.Clamp01(1f - Drag * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

The custom Physics class had to be reworked to require that the time increment be Unity's Time.fixedDeltaTime (the time between FixedUpdate calls)

```
public class SlingPhysics
{
    private Vector3 Gravity;
    private float Force, Mass, Drag;

    public void Init(Vector3 gravity, float force, float mass, float drag)
    {
        Gravity = gravity;
        Force = force;
        Mass = mass;
        Drag = drag;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Computes an array of Trajectory object positions by time.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Number of positions filled into the buffer</returns>
    /// <param name="startPos">Starting Position</param>
    /// <param name="direction">Direction (and magnitude) vector</param>
    /// <param name="yFloor">Minimum height, below which is clipped</param>
    /// <param name="positions">Buffer to fill with positions</param>
    public int GetPositions(Vector3 startPos, Vector3 direction, float yFloor, Vector3[] positions)
    {
        float timeIncrement = Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        int maxItems = positions.Length;
        int i = 0;
        Vector3 velocity = direction * Force / Mass;
        Vector3 pos = startPos;
        for (; i < maxItems; i++)
        {
            velocity += Gravity * timeIncrement;
            velocity *= Mathf.Clamp01(1f - Drag * timeIncrement);
            pos += velocity * timeIncrement;
            if (pos.y < yFloor)
                break;
            positions[i] = pos;
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> I could continue to try to change my physics model to match what Unity
>   is doing

No, don't do it. Whenever Unity is updated, physics stuff like that break. For example, Unity 4 and 5 physics are not the-same. Had to heavily modify my Unity 4 physics code to make it work properly.

The easiest solution to your problem is to **not** calculate anything at all. The way I do it is to create **two** projectiles. **Projectile1** is the main projectile that can be seen and shot. **Projectile2** is a hidden projectile that **can't** be seen by the player.

On drag mode, shoot **Projectile2**(hidden) then store the its path or position(Vector3) it has traveled through in a `List`. Use that stored path to draw your `Projectile Trajectory`.

You only need to shoot **Projectile2**(hidden) once and store the path. If during drag mode, the finger, mouse or drag moves to another position, then you have to **clear** the `List`, re-shoot **Projectile2**(hidden) once again, store the position to the `List` and then update your `Projectile Trajectory` again.

When the finger is released, you can now shot the **Projectile1**(main projectile) which is visible to the player.

If you are using `lineRenderer`, the number of `SetVertexCount` is the-same as the number of your `List.Count`. Drawing the lines can be easily done by looping over the positions in the `List`.

The result is always the-same no matter how many times Unity is updated.

Comment: I agree, trying mimic Unity Physics is a bad idea, I just didn't have a better one.  I think this is on the right track, but the projectile takes some time to reach it's target (it is a slingshot game), so if I take this approach, the trajectory will lag horribly as the player aims.  Is there a way I can shoot the hidden projectile and speed up time just for it so it doesn't lag?

Comment: @ThisGuy is this a 2D or 3D game? This depends on fast the object is shot and the view of the camera and there is a solution for that.

Comment: it is a 3d augmented reality game.  The camera is attached to the slingshot patch.  As the device moves, the camera moves, and thus the trajectory moves.  Projectiles fly relatively slowly as we have turned down gravity a bit.